# How to get all sales from all shops?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

There is `ICollection<InformationСontent> InformationСontents` in `Area` class. Schema: **Area -> Floor -> Place**

I'd like to get all InformationContent from all Area in all Floor in all Place. How to do it?

I have only 1 linq query that returns all InformationContent in Area by id:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<InformationСontent>> GetAreaInformationContentToList(int areaId)
{
     // version 1
     var sales = await _unitOfWork.Context.Areas.Include(x => x.Floor)
                                                .ThenInclude(x => x.Place)
                                                .Where(x => x.Id == areaId)
                                                .SelectMany(x => x.InformationСontents)
                                                .Where(x => x.ActiveTo > DateTime.Now)
                                                .ToListAsync();
     return sales;

     //version 2
     //var sales = await _unitOfWork.Context.Areas.FromSqlRaw("").ToListAsync();
 }

public class Area
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
        public string WorkingTime { get; set; }

        public bool? IsLableShow { get; set; }
        public bool? IsLogoShow { get; set; }

        public int FloorId { get; set; }
        public Floor Floor { get; set; }

        public int? AreaCategoryId { get; set; }
        public AreaCategory AreaCategory { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaImage> AreaImages { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AreaPoint> AreaPoints { get; set; }

        public ICollection<InformationСontent> InformationСontents { get; set; }
    }


public class Floor : IHaveId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public int PlaceId { get; set; }
        public Place Place { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AreaPoint> AreaPoints { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
        
    }



public class  Place : BaseEntity
    {
        //public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Adress { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]       
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string WebSiteURL { get; set; }
        public int? AreaInMeters { get; set; }
        public string WorkingTime { get; set; }

        public bool? IsLableShow { get; set; }
        public bool? IsLogoShow { get; set; }
        public bool ClockIsShowing { get; set; }
        public bool TickerIsShowing { get; set; }
        public string TickerText { get; set; }
        public bool WeatherIsShowing { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public int? FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File {get;set;}

        public ICollection<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
        public ICollection<StationMedia> StationMedias { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AreaCategoryType> AreaCategoryTypes { get; set; }
    }

public class InformationСontent : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int AreaId { get; set; } 
        public Area Area { get; set; }
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public FileModel File { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActiveTo { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Sounds like you basically just want to return everything that matches to the Area id, is that right?

Comment: @sr28 I want to return InformationContent from all Area in Place

Comment: If you want to get all Areas based on a place why is your method taking an area id as the input parameter?

Comment: @sr28 1. Looking for Area in Place by area id 
           2. Return all  InformationContent in Area

Comment: @sr28 how to get all InformationContent from all Area based on Place?

Comment: If an `Area` can exist separately from a `Floor` then just iterate over all `Area` objects in your data set to get the `InformationContent` records. If an `Area` must be attached to a `Floor` then you start at `Place.Floors`.